# How to convert Fashion MNIST to Dataset class?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning Tensorflow and would like to use `next_batch` for Fashion-MNIST data set. But I'm hitting a snag since the dataset for Fashion-MNIST is formatted differently than MNIST data.

For regular MNIST we can import data using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data as ip
mnist = ip.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

But the Tensorflow tutorial (URL: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification), imports Fashion-MNIST like so:

```
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) =  fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

I want to use Fashion-MNIST using this particular line of code:

```
 batch_xs, batch_ys = fashion_mnist.train.next_batch(100)
```

But when I attempt it using the Tensorflow tutorial's method of data importation I get this error:

```
 AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist' has no attribute 'train'
```

How can I convert Fashion-MNIST or import it differently in order to use this particular line of code?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the problem is that Keras built-in datasets are not defined using the `Dataset API`, but if you still want to use the Dataset class (which has a lot of advantages), there are several ways (I know of) to proceed.

1. you could create your own instance of the `Dataset` class, as has been done in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/the-artificial-impostor/tensorflow-fashion-mnist-with-dataset-api-cce1e3cc8cd4)
2. if you are using TensorFlow version >= 1.12.0, you could install the new [`tensorflow-datasets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets) library, which has Fashion MNIST as well, already loaded as `tf.Data.Datasets`

I hope this helps!

edit: just noticed that it doesn't answer your question completely. You won't be able to use the particular line of code you are talking about, since the function `next_batch` is defined in the `tf.contrib.learn` module for mnist specifically [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7c36309c37b04843030664cdc64aca2bb7d6ecaa/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L160). But you could then use `tf.Data.Iterator`, which iterates through the dataset and serves the same function.

Answer (score 2):

yes fashion mnist doesnt have next_batch or something you can use generator for batch iteration:

```
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) =  fashion_mnist.load_data()

batchs=(train_images[i*100:(i+1)*100],train_labels[i*100:(i+1)*100] for i in range(int(len(train_labels)/100)))

batch_xs, batch_ys=batchs.__next__()
```

but you dont need the split data to batchs in keras. fit() method has a `batch_size` parameter